# Stopwatch on Visual Basic without using timer feature

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a stopwatch using Visual basic but I have to do it without using the timer feature and use loops to make it instead. When I click the Stop Button, the time on the stopwatch label should transfer to the list box as laps (I haven't got that far yet). But I think to make the stopwatch actually start ticking I should use 4 nested loops for a millisecond, second, minute, an hour, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help would be amazing. Down below is what I have so far but I didn't use the 4 nested loops because I don't know how to put it in.

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
    Application.DoEvents()
    Dim Milliseconds, Seconds, Minutes, Hours As New Integer

    For Miliseconds = 1 To 1000
        If Miliseconds = 1000 Then
            Seconds += 1
        End If
    Next
    For Seconds = 1 To 59
        If Seconds = 60 Then
            Minutes += 1
        End If
    Next
    For Minutes = 1 To 59
        If Minutes = 60 Then
            Hours += 1
        End If
    Next
    For Hours = 1 To 23
        lblRacingTimer.Text = Hours & "" & ":" & "" & Minutes & "" & ":" & "" & Seconds & "" & ":" & "" & Milliseconds & "" & ":" & "" & ""
    Next
```

Comment: This isn't VBA code, it's VB.NET and they're two different languages.

Comment: Loops are certainly not the right way to go especially assuming that a loop executed in exactly one millisecond. You could use a loop and calculate the elapsed time from a known starting time, but I would look more towards events that are raised like maybe a background worker

Comment: The code you've posted isn't complete. Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: This approach seems like a really, really, really bad idea outside of a completely contrived example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starting implementatin for you, you would need to add cancellation and other features. You could use the timeSpan to get your elapsed hours/minute/seconds/milliseconds and format it properly:

```
Private Sub Stopwatch(Seconds As Integer)

    Dim startTime As DateTime
    Dim endTime As DateTime
    Dim currentTime As DateTime
    Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan

    startTime = DateTime.Now
    endTime = startTime.AddSeconds(Seconds)
    currentTime = startTime

    Do While currentTime < endTime

        currentTime = DateTime.Now
        timeSpan = currentTime - startTime

    Loop

End Sub
```

This would run the stopwatch for 12 hours:

```
Stopwatch(43200)
```